# How to know if a number is greater or smaller than a range?

Tags: ruby

```rb
(1..2) <=> 3 # => -1
(-2..21) <=> -10 # => 1
(-2..21) <=> 0 # => 0
```

Is there a ruby implemented method already for this function? Otherwise, I would code it myself.

Comment: Ranges have method `end`. I don't think a built-in method exists for this. Normally, you'd only be interested if a value is in the range, or not in the range (either "lower" or "greater")

Comment: Your method definition is inconsistent. Predicates are yes and no questions. If you mean greater just answer in terms of True and False.

Comment: I've corrected the question

Comment: `(1..2).end <=> 3`

Comment: But If the number is less than the start of the range, I'd like to return 1.

Comment: That's the opposite of the usual comparison, but there's nothing to say you couldn't make a method that does this.

Comment: @ChiaraAni: well, there's a method for start of the range too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can utilize [`clamp`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Comparable.html#clamp-method):

```
  3.clamp( 1..2 ) <=>   3  # => -1
-10.clamp(-2..21) <=> -10  # =>  1
  0.clamp(-2..21) <=>   0  # =>  0
```

in general:

```
number.clamp(range) <=> number
```

---

To get the "distance": (as stated in your original question)

```
number - number.clamp(range)
```

You can add [`nonzero?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Numeric.html#nonzero-3F-method) to get `nil` instead of `0`:

```
(number - number.clamp(range)).nonzero?
```

For example:

```
def distance(range, number)
  (number - number.clamp(range)).nonzero?
end

distance(1..2, 3)     #=> 1
distance(-2..21, -10) #=> -8
distance(1..4, 3)     #=> nil
```

Comment: I get `ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 2))` when type in ruby console `3.clamp( 1..2 )`

Comment: @ChiaraAni you need Ruby 2.7 or above to pass a range directly. For older Ruby versions you can use `3.clamp(1, 2)` instead.

Comment: I forgot about `clamp` (which I see it was introduced in v2.4). Perfect fit here, eh? I suggest you incorporate your comment above in your answer.

Comment: Whoops, this does not appear to work with three-dot ranges: "When `range.end` is excluded and not nil, an exception is raised."

Answer (score 2):

```
def where_is_val?(range, val)
  case val
  when range
    0
  when ..range.begin
    -1
  else
    1
  end
end
```

```
where_is_val?(0..10,  -1)  #=> -1
where_is_val?(0..10,   0)  #=>  0
where_is_val?(0..10,   5)  #=>  0
where_is_val?(0..10,  10)  #=>  0
where_is_val?(0..10,  15)  #=>  1
where_is_val?(0...10, 10)  #=>  1
```

```
where_is_val?('c'..'m',  'a')  #=> -1
where_is_val?('c'..'m',  'c')  #=>  0
where_is_val?('c'..'m',  'f')  #=>  0
where_is_val?('c'..'m',  'm')  #=>  0
where_is_val?('c'..'m',  'z')  #=>  1
where_is_val?('c'...'m', 'm')  #=>  1
```

Notice that this works with both inclusive (`0..10`) and exclusive (`0...10`) ranges.